# Is it possible to have excel highlight cells that don't conform to my desired format (ex. date as 6.2.2021 vs the desired 6/2/2021)?

Tags: excel, date, workflow, conditional-formatting

I use a spreadsheet to prioritize workflow for my team. Certain cells highlight depending on how close we are to cycle times. There is a start date, a tentative finish date, and a discharge date.

A blank discharge date cell turns red if:
start date is not blank; tentative is not blank; and today's date is within five days of the tentative date.

Some of my team member have the habit of writing their dates with periods (mm.dd.yyyy). Excel of course does not recognize this as a date. BUT it does know that the 'tentative date' cell is not blank. As a result, even if today's date is equal to the tentative date, the 'discharge date' cell does not turn red. This is taking away from the utility of this sheet, as it is intended to be info at a glance, where a glaring red cell lets one know, "Oh shoot! I need to focus on that task as a priority."

I'd like for the start date and tentative date cells to go red if the date is not the desired format (mm/dd/yyyy).

Formula and condition in S1:

S1 fills red if

**=AND($P1-TODAY()<=5,COUNTA($S1)=0,$M1<>0,$P1<>0)**

Comment: This could be an XY problem. Have you considered Data Validation to ensure only dates are entered in the date fields?

Comment: I agree with cybernetic.  try to solve the bad behaviour of your team, rather than dealing with the consequences.  As an alternative to data Validation (which is a good option) you could create a Worksheet_Change event to detect invalid entry and try to convert it to a valid date

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about accomplishing either of those, Data Validation or a Worksheet_Change event. I found a solution that worked from one of Euler's spawn. I'm guessing these two solution offer a more robust solution, but the answer was more than enough to do what I'm looking for. Also, in terms of modifying my team members' behaviors, this is going to do just that by giving them feedback in the moment. We are running extremely lean, so I don't have time to remind or use direct corrective action. Excel can add this to its list of functions I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way that you can conditionally format the output as red with your supplied formula above, you can conditionally format the inputs (start date and tentative date) if they do not match your criteria.

One idea is to use something like `=SEARCH(".", A1)>0` as the criteria for the format (if the incorrect input always comes in some variation of dd.mm.yyyy, and assuming the start of your range is in cell A1).

Here are the steps to do so if you did not create the original rule:

1. Highlight the ranges of the start and tentative dates
2. Go Home->Conditional Formatting->New Rule->"Use formula to determine which cells to format"
3. Enter the formula above (where you are sure to remove absolute references)
4. Go Format->Fill->Choose Red and hit okay

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic! What an easy solution. Thank you for this. It does exactly what I need it to do. Now just to get those pesky humans to do likewise, which this will help with by providing immediate feedback for their entries.

Comment: Ha! That is always the hard part... If you found that this answered your question feel free to accept it as the answer (the little check mark next to the up or down arrow).