# Excel Conditional Formatting with updating formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a matrix in excel (pictured below) that I need the following conditions for:
(1) A cell should be orange if a time fraction and Tj are provided on the same row, AND a Ball name is provided on its respective column
(2) A cell should be blue if, on the same row, any previous current input is <= .5* the first current input on the same row, regardless of if a ball name is provided
(3) A cell should be blue if no time fraction or Tj are provided on the same row, or if no ball name is given in its respective column
(4) The cells must default to blue when nothing is entered
At the moment, the cells are filled blue, so I understand that I need to only format when the cells should become orange, but I'm having some trouble working out the logic for conditional formatting, and as its a large table, I would like to avoid having to enter a conditional format for each individual cell.
Is there a way to say, for instance, (cell) = AND(tfrac <> "", tj <> "", Ballname <> "") format(orange), and then have the row/column numbers change for each cell, to that cell's respective column/row letter/number? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please provide picture of filled data and desired result for better understanding. Also post what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to conditional formatting, you can follow this answer I gave to a different question: [Is it possible to have excel highlight cells that don't conform to my desired format (ex. date as 6.2.2021 vs the desired 6/2/2021)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67812618/is-it-possible-to-have-excel-highlight-cells-that-dont-conform-to-my-desired-fo/67814289#67814289) which will show you how to go about it.

As to the actual conditional logic for the formula that will be used, I would try something like:

`=AND($time<>"", $tj<>"", ballname="what_you_want")`

[image]

Comment: Ahh, the dollar signs always trip me up. Thank you for your help, I've got it working now!