# Conditional Formatting to Highlight Rows Above

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet set up with columns for each day for a 2 week pay period (D thru Q) and the following the following rows:

1. Hours Worked (Cell D4)
2. Number of Reports (D5)
3. Number of EF Reports (D6)
4. Number of Reports/Hour (D7)

If the number of reports per hour (D7) is under 5.15, then I want the 4 row block for that day (D4:D7) to receive the conditional formatting.  Multiple employees are then entered sequentially down the sheet (D8:D11, D12:D15, etc.)  What formula would I need to enter to have this work?

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to conditional formatting, the answer in this link might help [Is it possible to have excel highlight cells that don't conform to my desired format (ex. date as 6.2.2021 vs the desired 6/2/2021)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67812618/is-it-possible-to-have-excel-highlight-cells-that-dont-conform-to-my-desired-fo/67814289#67814289)

For this specific case, try using the formula `=D$7<5.15` as your condition.

It is outside of your question, but I will note that it is generally best to have a separate row for each instance, and list the attributes in each column (i.e. column D is hours worked, column E is number of reports, column F is number of EF reports, etc.). If you rework your data to that layout, it will probably make your life easier

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if your conditional format range starts in D4:

```
=INDEX(D:D,FLOOR(ROW(D4),4)+3)<5.15
```

as a custom formula.

[image]

If you want the formatiing to apply right across the block from column D to column Q based on the figure in D7,D11 etc, change the formula to

```
=INDEX($D:$D,FLOOR(ROW($D4),4)+3)<5.15
```